# Why appium not working after upgrade to JDK 18?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I use Appium version 1.22.3. For some reason - after I updated my JDK from 11 to 18 I get the following exception while running my tests:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: jdk.proxy2.$Proxy10.proxyClassLookup()`

Why is this happening? It looks like it can't work with the new JDK.

Comment: Can you please share the source code project via github to reproduce & identify the above issue and figure out the fixes for the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.